# Rewrite URI when a certain file (no matter under which URI) is served?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, uri, canonicalization

Is it possible in `.htaccess` to redirect/rewrite (301) to a certain URI when a certain "physical" (static) file is served? It shouldn’t matter under which URI this file is served initially.

#### Example

In the document root of `example.com` there is a file `index.html`. This file can be accessed with different URIs (depending on server configuration), like:

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/index`
- `http://example.com/index.html`
- `http://example.com/index.html?foo=bar`
- `http://example.com///////////index.html`

With a (pseudo!) rule like `RewriteRule file(index.html) http://example.com/ [R=301,L]` I could specify the canonical URI for this file without having to think of all possible URI variations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from any of those URLs to `http://example.com/`, the following will work.

`RewriteRule ^index(\.html)?$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

The `(\.html)?` part is a regex lazy match for `.html` which means that `http://example.com/index` and `http://example.com/index.html` will both match. If you only wanted to redirect from all of the possible `index.html` requests, you can just omit the lazy search like so:

`RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Okay, this would certainly be a solution for the file in my example, but this operates on the URI level. So my question still holds: Is there a way to operate on file level? ((I didn’t include this in the example, but it should still work when there is an alias URI for the file, e.g. one that doesn’t include `index`. Or when there are various `index.*` files and one of it can include the file extension optionally. Or when different files can be accessed by the same URI (thanks to Content Negotiation).)) If there is no such way, I’d have to go with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Redirection from / to index.html

The transparent redirection from `/` to `index.html` is operated by [mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_dir.html) through the `DirectoryIndex` directive

If you want a redirection, you can use the `DirectoryIndexRedirect` directive:

```
 DirectoryIndexRedirect permanent
```

This would have the exact inverse effect of what you are trying to achieve as it will redirect http://example.com/ to http://example.com/index.htm

## 2. Redirection from index to index.html

The transparent redirection from `index` to  `index.html` is operated by the [`+MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option, when this option has been set in your Apache configuration or .htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

There's no configuration variable for issuing this redirection using HTTP 301 code.

## 3. Solution to your problem

You can detect the file chosen by Apache content negociation and `DirectoryIndex` using the variable `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. If this happens to be an index file, you can remove the url part after the last / if any

```
RewriteCond expr "%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -strmatch '*/index.*'"
RewriteRule (.*/)?(.*) $1 [R=301]
```